# How to fix CWE 117 (Improper Output Neutralization for Logs) by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, encode

The scan throw this error about this line:

```
console.log(msg);
```

I need this line on my code, but I want to change to more secure. I added this to my code:

```
var newMsg = msg.replace('\n', '_').replace('\r', '_');
```

Then I sent the `newMsg` to the log. I saw it isn't enough, I read that sometimes should to encoded the message. When should I encode it, and how can I do it in javascript/jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: If you look at the [error description](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/117.html) then it's simply because you're using the log. The only way to avoid the error is to not use the log. This is a valid concern, as outside of a dev environment you shouldn't have any `console.log()` calls in the logic.

Comment: Thanks, but we should the logs. How can I check the user didn't enter a risky value?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of CWE 117 (raw value log printing on production enviroments) you should go through mitigation steps on MITRE's [specification](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/117.html), this is:

**INPUT VALIDATION** code(before log printing) should :

- Disallow content (business logic specific)
- Escape HTML content :

  ```
  In:  `<p>Hello <script>this_is_bad_code</script> world!</p>`  
  Out: `&lt;p&gt;Hello &lt;script&gt;this_is_bad_code&lt;/script&gt; world!&lt;/p&gt;`
  ```
- Strip content :

  ```
  In:  <p>Hello <script>this_is_bad_code</script> world!</p>
  Out: Hello world!
  ```
- Clean content to get safe html (business logic specific) :

  ```
  In:  <p>Hello <script>this_is_bad_code</script> world!</p>
  Out: <p>Hello world!</p>
  ```

**OUTPUT DECODING**: This is a shabby one in js, as a js source file can have any kind of encoding, JavaScript will convert it to UTF-16 before executing it, still you can:

- Check if current page encoding tag value is up in header:

  ```
  Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
  ```
- Check if source js encoding tag value is up :

  ```
  <script src="./source.js" charset="utf-8">
  ```